# how to set callback URL using HybridAuth social login

Tags: authentication, yii, hybridauth

I using extensions HybridAuth version 2.8.2 for function login social.
How to set callback URL redirect to another page not homepage after login success.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the login redirect URi in the Hybridauth settings under Other Settings.